Setup XCode Cloud project which have multiple custom framework
I have a project, which have couple of pod files and along with that have two custom framework.
All the framework and main source is placed inside the Bitbucket.
I know the process to setup XCode Cloud for Pod files when main project contain only Pod files.
But can't setup the XCode Cloud for the main project, as I don't know the process to proceed with custom framework.
Need your kind help on this.
